# jQuery insert div only works on refresh

Tags: jquery, jsdom

I've used the following on a website's product page to generate a mailto: link with that product's name, and insert the div into an existing div for the product description

```
    var $emailsubject = $("h1.ProductItem-details-title").html();
    var $infoEmail = $("<div><a href='mailto:studio@ehgprop.co.uk?subject=RE: Prop Enquiry - "+$emailsubject+"'>Click here to enquire</a></div>");
    $("*[data-content-field='excerpt']").append ($infoEmail);
```

However, I'm finding that the code doesn't run on page load, and needs to be refreshed to work. I don't know if this is because it can't load the DOM information to make the link or what is going on

I've tried document.ready and pageinit or pagecreate but it doesn't seem to want to run until the information has already been loaded fully.

Is there a way to either have this run while the page is loading or trigger a single refresh so the visitor doesn't see the lapse in information?

ETA: example page here

This is through SquareSpace so I don't have much editing power with the html structure

ETA2: I've found the problem, it was an ajax loader setting. Just needed to be turned off

Comment: Can you give us more of your code? How is your HTML looking alike? Is the code you have given inside a function?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `$()` for `$infoEmail variable` so try below concept

```
var $emailsubject = $("h1.ProductItem-details-title").html();
    var $infoEmail ="<div><a href='mailto:studio@ehgprop.co.uk?subject=RE: Prop Enquiry - "+$emailsubject+"'>Click here to enquire</a></div>";
    $("*[data-content-field='excerpt']").append ($infoEmail);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but this doesn't do anything to change the issue unfortunately

Comment: You are using so long method for doing  this .. just get

Comment: $(whterver your selector).attr('href');